# Why splitting a line separated by spaces with stream in C++ runs infinitely?

Tags: c++

Before, when I was writing C++, I often used `getch()` for validation. However, now I am turning into competitive programming, I cannot use `getch()`; I had to use `cin` or `getline`. Thus, today, I replicated an instance of splitting a `string` using `stringstream`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line << endl;
    stringstream reader;
    reader.clear();
    reader.str(line);
    vector<long long int> list;
    while (true) {
        reader.clear();
        if (reader.str().size() == 0) {
            break;
        }
        long long int value;
        reader >> value;
        list.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

Then, I ran the program, typed `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and pressed enter. The program successfully displayed `line`, `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, but the program just didn't terminate. It never approached the end of the `main()` function. I tried to print `reader.str()`, but it just print `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` continually. I was confused. Why `reader >> value` didn't run and did not read any value? Why was the program running an infinite loop? How can I fix the issue? I appreciate any solution.

Comment: `while (true)` -- You literally have this in your program.  What did you expect this to do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I expect `reader.str().length() == 0` to terminate.

Comment: I have `break` in my code.

Comment: I'm reading your original question carefully, and you didn't mention anything about that statement.  A better question would have been concerning that line of code, because obviously you wrote an infinite `while` loop, *hoping* that it hits the `break` statement.

Comment: `while (reader >> value) { list.push_back(value); }` is a better way to express this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Firstly, `reader >> value` didn't read anything, so that would be my major concern. It didn't terminate because that statement isn't read.

Comment: @ChiangCliff -- I'll give you help on how you should have asked your question:  `Why is (reader.str().size() == 0) never true?`.  See how simple that was.  Also, to "clear" a `stringstream`, the `str("");` method is called, not `clear()`.

Comment: Stop spamming member calls you don't understand. What are you *really* trying to do? Extract `long long` values until (a) there are none, or (b) the string stream is exhausted? If so, this is clearly not the way to do it, especially since you never validate the actual value-extractions in the first place (e.g. `reader >> value` is completely unchecked). The code you wrote is constantly reading `1` from the stream, and examination of the `list` you're building would show that if you ran your code in a debugger. The proper approach is shown by Ninja above.

Comment: @WhozCraig Firstly, I do not mean to _validate_ anything, I mean to _split_ it, and I don't understand what is the difference between (a) and (b).

Comment: @ChiangCliff `1 2 3 4 xzy` on a single line will yield four values and finish with a string input stream that is *not* empty, but no longer has a readable `long long`. The sequence `1 2 3 4` would result in four values and leave the stream completely exhausted (no content, numeric or otherwise, remains). That's the difference. Doing [what RetiredNinja suggested](https://godbolt.org/z/6dxfo4dje) is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reading `operator >>` does not change the underlying string. It uses an inner position of a next char to read.

```
int main() {
    int n;
 
    std::istringstream in;  // could also use in("1 2")
    in.str("1 2");
    in >> n;
    std::cout << "after reading the first int from \"1 2\", the int is "
              << n << ", str() = \"" << in.str() << "\"\n";
 
}
```

Outputs

```
after reading the first int from "1 2", the int is 1, str() = "1 2"
```

The loop may be terminated by replacing `reader >> value;` with

```
if (!(reader >> value))
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... but the program just didn't terminate.

This means that ...

```
while (true)
```

true is never false, or ...

```
reader.str().size() == 0
```

is never true.

true, in fact, is *never* false, and you never change the size of the reader's string object.  Why would you expect this loop to break?

Please edit your question to make it more clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from context that he _does_ think he is changing the size of `reader.str().size()`; otherwise he wouldn't have written the loop that way.